# SQL Syntax error, while formulating Django queryset using extra

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

In a Django app named *links*, at one point I run the following code on a queryset, and getting the error: **column user_id does not exist**:

```
date = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
groups = Group.objects.filter(private='0').extra(select = {
  "views" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM links_grouptraffic
    JOIN links_group on links_grouptraffic.which_group_id = links_group.id
  WHERE links_grouptraffic.visitor_id = user_id
  AND links_grouptraffic.time > %s """}, select_params=(date,),
).order_by("-views")
```

The user_id in this code is a reference to a `Django.contrib.auth` `user`. I have not overridden this in any way.

**Other things I've tried:**

If I change `user_id` to `user.id`, I get the error: **syntax error at or near "."** This is thrown in reference to the line `WHERE links_grouptraffic.visitor_id = user_id.`

If I change `user_id` to `links_user.id`, I get the error: **missing FROM-clause entry for table "links_user"**

If I change `user_id` to `user` (and correspondingly, `visitor_id` to `visitor`), I get the error: **column links_grouptraffic.visitor does not exist** (`visitor` is a foreign key to `user`, hence ought to be `visitor_id`).

---

Related models are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)])
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    private = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupTraffic(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are You sure Your `group` model has a `user_id` column?

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup: Group model, or grouptraffic model?

Comment: this: `groups = Group.objects.filter(private='0')`

Comment: Group model has the attribute `owner = models.ForeignKey(User)` and grouptraffic model has the attribute `visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owner_id` not `user_id`:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM links_grouptraffic
    JOIN links_group on links_grouptraffic.which_group_id = links_group.id
  WHERE links_grouptraffic.visitor_id = owner_id
  AND links_grouptraffic.time > %s
```

Comment: Don't forget [to vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Voting promotes good answers.